# semantic-ui grid CDN doesn't work with react?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm creating a simple giphy search app with react. All the classes in semantic-ui seem to work except for the grid system, specifically creating columns from the gifs that are pulled in on search, they're all just lining up vertically. This isn't the first time I've run into this problem, and I'm hoping one of you can figure out what I'm doing wrong, I don't want to solve this with bootstrap again lol.

I have downloaded and imported semantic-ui-react into my react projects and that syntax does not seem to work either.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

const SearchBar = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="ui input">
      <input
        value={props.value} 
        placeholder="Find the gif of your dreams!" 
        type="text"
        onChange={e => props.onSearchInput(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const DisplayGifs = (props) => {

  const gifs = props.data.map(gif => {
    return (
      <div className="column">
        <div class="ui card" key={gif.id}>
          <div class="image">
            <img src={gif.images.fixed_width_downsampled.url} alt={gif.id} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  })

  return (
    <div>{gifs}</div>
  );
}

class App extends Component {
  state = { searchTerm: '', gifs: [] }

  onSearchInput = (term) => {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: term })
  }

  onHandleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const gifs = await axios.get('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=' + this.state.searchTerm + '&api_key=MRLay8p2J7b0XwOwbZOJVCau52Fn4B6R&limit=8')
    this.setState({ searchTerm: '', gifs: gifs.data.data })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.gifs)
    return (
      <div className="ui container">
        <h1>Gify Search API</h1>
        <div className="ui segment">
          <form onSubmit={this.onHandleSubmit}>
            <SearchBar 
              value={this.state.searchTerm}
              onSearchInput={this.onSearchInput}
            />
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className="ui three column grid">
          <DisplayGifs 
            data={this.state.gifs}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your App component, where you are returning `<DisplayGifs>`, it is wrapped with your grid div `<div className="ui three column grid">`. However in your `<DisplayGifs>` component you are returning `<div>{gifs}</div>` so when rendered your html is :

```
<div className="ui three column grid">
  <div>
    <div className="column">...</div>
    <div className="column">...</div>
    <div className="column">...</div>
    ...etc
  </div>
</div>
```

to fix this in your `<DisplayGifs>` component, do:

```
return gifs
```

Instead of

```
return (
  <div>{gifs}</div>
);
```

this way your rendered html will look like :

```
<div className="ui three column grid">
   <div className="column">...</div>
   <div className="column">...</div>
   <div className="column">...</div>
   ...etc
</div>
```

By returning `<div>{gifs}</div>` , it is breaking the structure semantic ui is looking for, which is direct children of a div with class grid having the column class